# Making an iPhone app on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have an app available for the iPhone only now not the iPad. I've already released 2 updates for the app(current version 1.2). Im about to release a third and in this update im adding a feature but thought Id also make it compatible for the iPad. Will apple accept that? Will I have to make a new project file for the iPad version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create the new project. There are two ways to solve your problem.

- Change the device target to Universal and also change the logic to support both iPhone and iPad.  In applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method put a condition to check the device.If the device is iPhone then load the iPhone screens and if not then load the iPad screens. This case when you upload the binary to App Store then the version number is same for both the binaries(iPhone & iPad) .
- Change the device target to iPad and also change the version number whichever you want. For this also need to create separate nibs and change the logic to load only the iPad screens in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. For this case need to upload a separate binary with your specific version.The advantage of this step is you can make it as paid app for iPad or iPhone.

Note: My suggestion is if both are free apps then go with 1st step. If not then go with 2nd step. Still if you are not clarified feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *have* to submit a separate project because all iOS applications are supported by the iPad by default, but you can if you feel the need to.

Right-click your target, and select "*Upgrade current target for iPad*".

I'd also recommend reading through [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) on the subject.